# Prevent angular from sorting list item alphabetically in real time

Tags: angularjs, list, sorting

I am trying to fix a bug with an angularjs list.

When an item in the list is edited, the record is sorted alphetically in real time and it jumps to a new position in the list.

This is proving problematic as when someone tries to edit a record, "ABC" for example, if they put a "Z" in front of it it jumps to the last page on the list.

The text input value is bound directly to the model, which I suspect is the issue, as the data-ng-repeat directive ensures that the data is sorted alphabetically.

As such I tried changing the data-ng-model binding to data-ng-bind, as it is my understanding that if the input value is changed, ng-model updates the model while ng-bind doesn't.

I would greatly appreciate any advice.

HTML:

```
<form name="companies" class="clearfix" novalidate data-ng-  hide="loadingIcon">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="company in data | orderBy: 'NAME' | siftPage: startIndex: endIndex">
                <td width="60%">
                    <span data-ng-hide="edit"> {{ company.NAME }} </span>

                    <div class="form-field col-sm-9" data-ng-show="edit">
                        <input type="text" data-ng-bind="company.NAME" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="icon edit" data-ng-click="edit = !edit; changed = edit ? edited(company) : changed(company);" href="#"></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="icon delete" data-ng-click="removeCompany(company)" href="#"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I'm new to angular so please forgive me if I haven't included enough information. I will update update with any further information as requested.

Comment: Do you want the data to sort as soon as the edit is complete?  Or never sort again after the first rendering?  There are two possible solutions, depending on your desired outcome here.

Comment: Considering the fact that the user may have to edit multiple records after each other it would make sense to reorder the list when the user is finished updating it.

Comment: if you are meaning to say that you want the re-ordering to only happen after multiple edits are complete, then you would need some way for the user to signify that the edits are complete (save button, traditionally).  this button could then fire the sorting function, instead of the `orderBy:`, similar to the offered answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is the ng-repeat with the orderBy: 'Name' clause that is the actual issue.  It will make sure that the order is maintained even after an edit.

If you want to order initially before edits, copy the name as initialName onto each of your json objects and set the orderBy to 'initialName'.  Since you wont be updating the initialName on an edit it wont update via the order by.

If you create the copy as a function to create the initialNames, you could call it through a button to re-sort the data.